# Get routes in Flask that return only templates/html pages

Tags: python, flask, routes

My routes in my Flask app sometimes return HTML, but also other things that returns data for information requests. How can I use app.url_map (or any other methods) to get the routes that only return HTML? I tried reading the documentation [here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map) but it's too difficult for me as a beginner.

Comment: Do you have a lot of routes? Can't you do it manually or with some script that will work on your code that includes the routes as text? For example, i would try to create a list with pairs of code lines that include @app.route and render_template and investigate that list

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a hard question. Usually, the flask returns responses which include the HTML. It may also return JSON, for example. It is hard to distinguish those unless executing each root -- values are often assigned dynamically.

If you can execute each route safely, then try using `pycurl` to get the response/JSON/whatever and distinguish the later. An additional challenge is that while flask allows different output types depending on request (say, a POST request reads the form and returns JSON if JSON is selected and the HTML otherwise)

I really like @IoaTzimas suggestion: if your program is simple, run a script that checks which handlers precede the `render_template` statement. But sometimes the code may return the instance of `Response` class, and if so, the level of the challenge is high.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution; instead of using app’s methods I instead read the file names inside the template folder and isolate the ones ending with “html”, then return this list